# jSON format data from SOAP Web service in Android

Tags: android

I try to parse Parse JSON format data from SOAP Web service in Android but throw the An Error occurred while processing output information.Here I paste the Logcat, browser output of service.Could anybody guide to me  what's wrong in my code?

```
String NAMESPACE = "http://dyndns.biz/AndroidService/";
String METHOD_NAME = "GetItemCategory";
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://dyndns.biz/AndroidService/GetItemCategory";
String URL = "http://dyndns.biz/AndroidService/Service.asmx";
String strDate ="26/07/2014";
SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
Request.addProperty("CreateDate", strDate);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
System.out.println("aht requestDump is :"+ androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
System.out.println("aht responseDump is :"+ androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
String responseJSON=response.toString();
JSONArray jarray =new JSONArray(responseJSON);
final String TAG_ID = "Id";    
final String TAG_NAME = "CategoryName";
final String TAG_CODE = "CategorCode";
 final String TAG_ACTIVE = "Active";
final String TAG_CREATEDATE="Createdate";
String  Name=jarray.getJSONObject(0).getString(TAG_NAME);
String  Id=jarray.getJSONObject(0).getString(TAG_ID);
String  Active=jarray.getJSONObject(0).getString(TAG_ACTIVE);
String  Code=jarray.getJSONObject(0).getString(TAG_CODE);
String  CreateDate =jarray.getJSONObject(0).getString(TAG_CREATEDATE);
```

json response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
 <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
  <faultstring>An Error occurred while processing output information.</faultstring>
<detail />
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
<v:Body>
<GetItemCategory xmlns="http://everestmrm.dyndns.biz:81/AndroidService/" 
id="o0" c:root="1">
<CreateDate i:type="d:string">26/07/2014</CreateDate>
</GetItemCategory>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

Thanks for Reply  My  LogCat:

```html
LogCat:

06-18 16:17:49.279: W/System.err(972): SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'An Error occurred while processing output information.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@4185aa40
06-18 16:17:49.281: W/System.err(972):  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:136)
06-18 16:17:49.282: W/System.err(972):  at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:137)
06-18 16:17:49.282: W/System.err(972):  at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:100)
06-18 16:17:49.283: W/System.err(972):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:195)
06-18 16:17:49.284: W/System.err(972):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
06-18 16:17:49.287: W/System.err(972):  at com.neotransit.mrmc.download$4.onClick(download.java:379)
06-18 16:17:49.288: W/System.err(972):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
06-18 16:17:49.289: W/System.err(972):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
06-18 16:17:49.290: W/System.err(972):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-18 16:17:49.291: W/System.err(972):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-18 16:17:49.293: W/System.err(972):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-18 16:17:49.294: W/System.err(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
06-18 16:17:49.295: W/System.err(972):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 16:17:49.296: W/System.err(972):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 16:17:49.297: W/System.err(972):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
06-18 16:17:49.299: W/System.err(972):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
06-18 16:17:49.300: W/System.err(972):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 16:17:49.300: D/jdwp(972): sendRequest : Len=0x32
06-18 16:17:49.301: D/jdwp(972): processIncoming
06-18 16:17:49.301: D/jdwp(972): handlePacket : cmd=0x2, cmdSet=0xF, len=0x10, id=0xD5C, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x5
06-18 16:17:49.301: D/jdwp(972): REQ: EventRequest.Clear (cmd=15/2 dataLen=5 id=0x000d5c)
06-18 16:17:49.301: D/jdwp(972): reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
06-18 16:17:49.303: D/jdwp(972): processIncoming
06-18 16:17:49.303: D/jdwp(972): handlePacket : cmd=0x6, cmdSet=0xB, len=0x1B, id=0xD5D, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x10
06-18 16:17:49.303: D/jdwp(972): REQ: ThreadReference.Frames (cmd=11/6 dataLen=16 id=0x000d5d)
06-18 16:17:49.303: D/jdwp(972): reply: dataLen=352 err=NONE(0)
06-18 16:17:49.304: D/jdwp(972): processIncoming
06-18 16:17:49.304: D/jdwp(972): handlePacket : cmd=0x7, cmdSet=0xB, len=0x13, id=0xD5E, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
06-18 16:17:49.304: D/jdwp(972): REQ: ThreadReference.FrameCount (cmd=11/7 dataLen=8 id=0x000d5e)
06-18 16:17:49.304: D/jdwp(972): reply: dataLen=4 err=NONE(0)
06-18 16:17:49.314: D/jdwp(972): processIncoming
06-18 16:17:49.314: D/jdwp(972): handlePacket : cmd=0x3, cmdSet=0x10, len=0x1B, id=0xD5F, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x10
06-18 16:17:49.314: D/jdwp(972): REQ: StackFrame.ThisObject (cmd=16/3 dataLen=16 id=0x000d5f)
06-18 16:17:49.314: D/jdwp(972): reply: dataLen=9 err=NONE(0)
06-18 16:17:49.316: D/jdwp(972): processIncoming
06-18 16:17:49.316: D/jdwp(972): handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xB, len=0x13, id=0xD60, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
06-18 16:17:49.316: D/jdwp(972): REQ: ThreadReference.Name (cmd=11/1 dataLen=8 id=0x000d60)
06-18 16:17:49.316: D/jdwp(972): reply: dataLen=12 err=NONE(0)
06-18 16:17:49.317: D/jdwp(972): processIncoming
06-18 16:17:49.317: D/jdwp(972): handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0x9, len=0x13, id=0xD61, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
06-18 16:17:49.317: D/jdwp(972): REQ: ObjectReference.ReferenceType (cmd=9/1 dataLen=8 id=0x000d61)
06-18 16:17:49.317: D/jdwp(972): reply: dataLen=9 err=NONE(0)
```

Browser Output:

[["69","TESTDEMO","True","TEST","26/07/2014 2:51:59 PM"]]

Comment: I added my logcat  kindly update what  error  i  did?

Comment: mark in which line error occurs - LogCat says it's `SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:136`, but we cannot see line numbers ;)

Comment: This line  exception occured : SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `client` faultcode: 
"The content generated by the client is incorrect or malformed. Therefore, resending the same data will result in the same error. In SOAP 1.2, this fault is being changed to Sender." (from https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/java-web-services/0596002696/ch04s02.html)
So probably your soap request is wrong - malformed or with wrong (other than expected for speciefied service) data

Comment: valid your request ;) you can do this by print it before send and check it with schema, or simply paste it to firefox or chrome soap plugin and try send - this way you will know if problem is with your request or with something else